# Error panic code 0x32 when testing with Hardhat **Solved**

Tags: solidity, hardhat, multisignature

When I try to test this contract with Hardhat I get the next error related to the "Approve Transaction with the 3 accounts" test. But I have no idea why this error is triggered.

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic
> code 0x32 (Array accessed at an out-of-bounds or negative index)

Could someone help? Please.

**Smart contract MultiSigWallet.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract MultiSigWallet {
    event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
    event SubmitTransaction(uint256 indexed txId);
    event ApproveTransaction(address indexed owner, uint256 indexed txId);
    event RevokeTransaction(address indexed owner, uint256 indexed txId);
    event ExecuteTransaction(uint256 indexed txId);

    struct Transaction {
        address payable to;
        uint256 amount;
        bytes data;
        bool executed;
        uint256 numConfirmations;
    }

    Transaction[] public transactions;

    address[] owners;
    mapping(address => bool) isOwner;

    // mapping from tx index => owner => bool
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => bool)) approved;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) executed;
    uint256 confirmationsRequired;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner[msg.sender], "You are not an owner");
        _;
    }

    modifier txNotApproved(uint256 _txId) {
        require(
            !approved[_txId][msg.sender],
            "The transaction is already approved"
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier txNotExecuted(uint256 _txId) {
        require(
            !transactions[_txId].executed,
            "The transaction has been already executed"
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier txExists(uint256 _txId) {
        require(
            transactions.length >= _txId,
            "The transaction does not exists"
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor(address[] memory _owners, uint256 _confirmationsRequired) {
        require(_owners.length > 0, "Owners needs to be greater than 0");
        require(
            _confirmationsRequired > 0,
            "Owners required needs to be greater than 0"
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; _owners.length > i; i++) {
            address _owner = _owners[i];
            require(_owner != address(0));
            isOwner[_owners[i]] = true;
        }
        owners = _owners;
        confirmationsRequired = _confirmationsRequired;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value, address(this).balance);
    }

    function submitTransaction(
        uint256 _amount,
        address payable _to,
        bytes memory _data
    ) public onlyOwner {
        transactions.push(
            Transaction({
                to: _to,
                amount: _amount,
                data: _data,
                executed: false,
                numConfirmations: 0
            })
        );
        uint256 txIndex = transactions.length;

        emit SubmitTransaction(txIndex);
    }

    function approveTransaction(uint256 _txId)
        public
        onlyOwner
        txExists(_txId)
        txNotApproved(_txId)
        txNotExecuted(_txId)
    {
        transactions[_txId].numConfirmations += 1;
        approved[_txId][msg.sender] = true;

        emit ApproveTransaction(msg.sender, _txId);
    }

    function revokeConfirmation(uint256 _txId)
        public
        onlyOwner
        txExists(_txId)
        txNotExecuted(_txId)
    {
        require(
            approved[_txId][msg.sender] = true,
            "This Transaction is not approved by the msg.sender"
        );
        approved[_txId][msg.sender] = false;

        emit RevokeTransaction(msg.sender, _txId);
    }

    function executeTransaction(uint256 _txId)
        public
        payable
        onlyOwner
        txNotExecuted(_txId)
        txExists(_txId)
    {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_txId];
        require(
            transaction.numConfirmations >= confirmationsRequired,
            "Not enough confirmations from the Owners"
        );

        transaction.executed = true;
        uint256 _transactionAmount = transaction.amount;
        address payable _to = transaction.to;
        _to.transfer(_transactionAmount);

        emit ExecuteTransaction(_txId);
    }

    function getOwners() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return owners;
    }

    function checkExecuted(uint256 _txId) public view returns (bool) {
        return executed[_txId];
    }

    function getTransactions() public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactions.length;
    }

    function getConfirmations(uint256 _txId) public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactions[_txId].numConfirmations;
    }
}
```

**Testing script (Hardhat)**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { loadFixture } = require("ethereum-waffle");
const { TransactionDescription } = require("ethers/lib/utils");

// Ganache accounts (Testnet):
// 1: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
// 2: 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
// 3: 0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC
// 4: 0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906

describe("MultiSigWallet", function () {
  async function deploy() {
    const MultiSigWallet = await ethers.getContractFactory("MultiSigWallet");
    const multiSigWallet = await MultiSigWallet.deploy(
      [
        "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
        "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8",
        "0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC",
      ],
      3
    );
    await multiSigWallet.deployed();

    console.log("* MultiSigWallet contract has been deployed.");
    console.log("* MultiSigWallet contract address:", multiSigWallet.address);

    return { multiSigWallet };
  }

  it("Check the Owners array length", async () => {
    const { multiSigWallet } = await loadFixture(deploy);
    const owners = await multiSigWallet.getOwners();
    expect(owners.length).to.equal(3);
  });

  it("Submit a new transaction", async () => {
    const { multiSigWallet } = await loadFixture(deploy);
    await multiSigWallet.submitTransaction(
      6,
      "0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906",
      "0x6e65775f6d6963726f7761766500000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    );
    const transactions = await multiSigWallet.getTransactions();

    expect(transactions).to.equal(1);
  });

  it("Transfer 5 ethers from the 3 owners to the contract and check SC balance", async () => {
    const { multiSigWallet } = await loadFixture(deploy);
    const [deployer, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
    await deployer.sendTransaction({
      to: multiSigWallet.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("2.0"),
    });
    await addr1.sendTransaction({
      to: multiSigWallet.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("2.0"),
    });
    await addr2.sendTransaction({
      to: multiSigWallet.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("2.0"),
    });

    const ScBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(multiSigWallet.address);
    expect(ScBalance).to.equal("6000000000000000000"); // 6000000000000000000 = 6 ethers
  });

  it("Approve Transaction with the 3 accounts", async () => {
    const { multiSigWallet } = await loadFixture(deploy);
    const [deployer, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    await multiSigWallet.connect(deployer).approveTransaction(1);
    await multiSigWallet.connect(addr1).approveTransaction(1);
    await multiSigWallet.connect(addr2).approveTransaction(1);

    const confirmations = await multiSigWallet.getConfirmations(1);

    expect(confirmations).to.equal(3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in line 51

```
        require(
            transactions.length >= _txId,
            "The transaction does not exists"
        );
```

Replace it with

```
        require(
            transactions.length > _txId,
            "The transaction does not exist"
        );
```

Comment: Transanctions.length needs to be greater or equal to the _txId, as the array can contain different transactions. This does not look to be the problem, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**I just solved the problem.** I was pointing to an different position in the array.

**Before**:

```
await multiSigWallet.connect(deployer).approveTransaction(1);
await multiSigWallet.connect(addr1).approveTransaction(1);
await multiSigWallet.connect(addr2).approveTransaction(1);

const confirmations = await multiSigWallet.getConfirmations(1);
```

**After**:

```
await multiSigWallet.connect(deployer).approveTransaction(0);
await multiSigWallet.connect(addr1).approveTransaction(0);
await multiSigWallet.connect(addr2).approveTransaction(0);

const confirmations = await multiSigWallet.getConfirmations(0);
```

I leave it here in case someone has the same error in the future.